# Vertical Navigation - Load Html page on Click

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I am working on a vertical accordion navigation menu.

For each sub-menu I created an HTML page that I want to display. In short, when I click on sub-menu "Reports", I want to display the red box (see code below) on the page and keep the navigation menu showing.

Simple question, sorry but where, in my code, am I supposed to do this and how? My first guess was to direct the sub-menu to my external html file but so far what I have done allows me to re-direct to another HTML page only, the navigation menu then disappears.

Do I need to create a sort of "container" next to the navigation menu?

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wp8kxa96/) of the navigation menu.

And below is the HTML code:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang=''>
    <head>

        <style type="text/css">

    body {
      width: 1280px;
      height: 720px;
      background-color: #E0EBEB;
    }

    </style>
       <meta charset='utf-8'>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="script.js"></script>
       <title>DCA Application</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="sidebar">
                <h1>Sidebar</h1>
    </div>

    <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>

       <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
       <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Past</span></a>
          <ul>
<!-- I do not get the result I want if I put "Reports.html" down here -->
             <li><a href='#'><span>Reports</span></a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Present</span></a>
          <ul>
             <li><a href='#'><span>DDS</span></a></li>
             <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Load Management</span></a></li>
          </ul>
           <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Future</span></a>
          <ul>
             <li><a href='#'><span>To be defined</span></a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       </li>
       <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Support</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>       
       </body>
    <html>
```

And the code for one of the html pages:

```
<html>
    <head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<!-- css part -->

    <style type="text/css">
        <style type="text/css">
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#blackbox{
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
width:200px;
height:200px;
margin-top:-100px;
margin-left:-100px;
border:1px solid black;
height: 90px;
line-height: 90px;
text-align:center; 
vertical-align:middle;
}

</style>

        </style>

<!-- css part end -->
<!-- html part beg -->

</head>
    <body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="main">

    <div id="blackbox"> 
    <div style="background-color:"> 
    <div class="results"> </div> 
    </div>
   </div>

<!-- html part end -->

<!-- js part -->

<script language="JavaScript"  type="text/javascript">

        var color1 = "#800080";
    var color2 = "#FF0000";
    var result = 1;
    document.querySelector('.results').innerHTML = result;
    if (result < 0) {
    document.querySelector('div').style.backgroundColor = color1;
    } else {
    document.querySelector('div').style.backgroundColor = color2;
    }

        </script>   

<!-- js part -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your fiddle why are you using document ready function again?

Comment: as per my understanding if you want sub menu expanded when you navigate to different page then get the  url and find the a tag with attr href having val == url. find its parent and toggle them.

Comment: @Raider I added the code for one of the other html pages (a basic red box...I start small). When clicking on sub-menu Reports, I want the red box to appear. I do not have any "a tag with attr href having val == url." I am only beginning in html/js, could you please give me more details?

Comment: @Aurax22 Your pages that are linked to do not have the accordion menu included in their code. You should include your menu on each page, with some server-side language like PHP or just copy the code into each file. Then you should do what Raider says: check the address of the page and check all the links in your accordion menu until you find the one which has the same address in the href attribute. Having found the matching link, you should toggle its accordion state. If you do not want to include the menu in each page, you could google for frames, iframes or AJAX.

Comment: @MatveyAndreyev Thanks for the details! I am looking now into AJAX and will post if manage.

Comment: one more option is get the title of the page like this   :var title = document.title; set the id or title attr on each ul like <ul id=title> or <ul title=title>  find this ul  using jquery $("ul[title]").slideDown()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1
Set the id or title attr on each ul like

```
    <ul id=title> or <ul title=title>

    //Get the title of the page like this

    var title = document.title; 

    //find this ul  using jquery 
    $("ul[title='title']").slideDown();
//or
    $('#'+title).slideDown();
```

Option 2
Try this. i have only added three lines with comments. you might have to split the actual url. I am sure you can do that easily.

```
    ( function( $ ) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
  //get the url  
var  url =$(location).attr('href');

//find the a tag having this url and its parent
      var tag =$( "a[href='url']" ).parent().parent();
//slide it down   
 $(tag).slideDown('normal')
    $('#cssmenu > ul > li ul').each(function(index, e){
      var count = $(e).find('li').length;
      var content = '<span class=\"cnt\">' + count + '</span>';
      $(e).closest('li').children('a').append(content);
    });
    $('#cssmenu ul ul li:odd').addClass('odd');
    $('#cssmenu ul ul li:even').addClass('even');
    $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
      $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 
      var checkElement = $(this).next();
      if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
      }
      if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
      }
      if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;   
      }     
    });

    });
    } )( jQuery );
```